# Finatra TooLongMessageException HTTP content length exceeded 5242880 bytes, despite flag setting more bytes

Tags: java, scala, http, finagle, finatra

I'm seeing a 
`TooLongMessageException HTTP content length exceeded 5242880 bytes.` exception thrown from my finatra server. Looking at the flags available via `-help=true`, it looks like the flag to set is `maxRequestSize`. Here is the output of the help command

```
flags:
  -admin.announce='java.lang.String': Address for announcing admin server
  -admin.port=':9990': Admin http server port
  -cert.path='': path to SSL certificate
  -doc.root='': File serving directory/namespace for classpath resources
  -help='false': Show this help
  -http.announce='java.lang.String': Address for announcing HTTP server
  -http.name='http': Http server name
  -http.port=':8080': External HTTP server port
  -http.response.charset.enabled='true': Return HTTP Response Content-Type UTF-8 Charset
  -https.announce='java.lang.String': Address for announcing HTTPS server
  -https.name='https': Https server name
  -https.port='': HTTPs Port
  -key.path='': path to SSL key
  -local.doc.root='': File serving directory for local development
  -log.append='true': If true, appends to existing logfile. Otherwise, file is truncated.
  -log.async='true': Log asynchronously
  -log.async.inferClassNames='false': Infer class and method names synchronously. See com.twitter.logging.QueueingHandler
  -log.async.maxsize='4096': Max queue size for async logging
  -log.level='INFO': Log level
  -log.output='/dev/stderr': Output file
  -log.rollPolicy='Never': When or how frequently to roll the logfile. See com.twitter.logging.Policy#parse documentation for DSL details.
  -log.rotateCount='-1': How many rotated logfiles to keep around
  -maxRequestSize='5242880.bytes': HTTP(s) Max Request Size
  -mustache.templates.dir='templates': templates resource directory
  -shutdown.time='1.minutes': Maximum amount of time to wait for pending requests to complete on shutdown
  -thrift.announce='java.lang.String': Address for announcing Thrift server
  -thrift.name='thrift': Thrift server name
  -thrift.port=':9999': External Thrift server port
  -thrift.shutdown.time='1.minutes': Maximum amount of time to wait for pending requests to complete on shutdown
```

I've passed in `-maxRequestSize=10.megabytes` and can see the value in the `/admin/registry.json` document: `maxRequestSize: "10485760.bytes"` but I'm *still* seeing the `TooLongMessageException` with the 5 megabyte value. How do I increase this max size?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe in code it is being overwritten?

You could do it programmatically

```
> override def configureHttpServer(server: Http.Server): Http.Server = {
>     server.withAdmissionControl.concurrencyLimit(maxConcurrentRequests = 2000, maxWaiters = 0)
>       .withResponseClassifier(HttpResponseClassifier.ServerErrorsAsFailures)
>       .withMaxRequestSize(StorageUnit.fromMegabytes(200))
>       .withRequestTimeout(50.seconds)   }
```